# How to resolve WSDL2Java creating a static block larger than 64K?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, axis, wsdl2java

We're currently working with a vendor-provided WSDL schema that is very large. The binding style is RPC. As far as I know, Axis 1.x is the only Java tool supporting RPC WSDL definitions. Please do correct me if I'm wrong about that.

WSDL2Java generates a ***service-name*Skeleton.java** file that has a static intialisation block 1.3Mb in size - considerably larger than Java's 64K limit.

**Given that we can't change the definition of the interface, how do you think we should proceed?**

Our options as I see them are:

- Break up the generated static block
- Break up the WSDL (not sure if that's possible without altering the interface)
- Patch the Axis WSDL2Java code

Any other ideas?

Comment: Yo, revisiting my old SO action. Anyway, since we couldn't get the vendor to modify their crappy SOAP tooling, I wrote a Perl script to bust the generated Java class' static initialisation block into smaller chunks. Insane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [article](http://wso2.org/library/knowledge-base/convert-rpc-encoded-wsdl-document-literal-wrapped-wsdl), which gives some instructions on how you can convert a RPC WSDL to a document one. I recommend trying that first.

Also, you probably have an RPC/encoded WSDL (which by the way, doesn't conform to WS-I). JAXWS only supports RPC/literal. So any framework (like CXF or Axis2) will support it. So, you can also try to convert the WSDL to RPC/literal.

CXF has a [tool](http://cwiki.apache.org/CXF20DOC/wsdl-to-soap.html) that could do the job for you.

Anyway, I recommend trying to convert the WSDL to a more recent form. This will make your life easier, both for the server and the client implementations. I don't believe that is worth fighting with Axis1. Even manually writing and parsing the SOAP messages could be easier.

Answer (score 1):

If your wsdl is likely to change frequently, it could be worth patching the wsdl2java code, otherwise I would go for the first option.